# How to create a vector of heterogeneous templated objects

Tags: c++, templates

```
class A{
};

template<typename T> class TemplatedA: public A {
 update(T t);
};
```

Now I want to use it like this

```
vector<A*> avec;
avec.emplace_back(new TemplatedA<int>());
avec.emplace_back(new TemplatedA<float>());

/////
int num1;
float num2;
avec[0]->update(num1)
avec[1]->update(num2)
```

I want to accomplish the above. But it wouldn't compile obviously as it is, how can we accomplish this?

Comment: Your base class has no knowledge of the `update` function, so obviously you cannot use that via a pointer to `A`. And since the type of the argument changes you'd probably need to use a downcast there as well

Comment: _"But it doesn't compile"_  You were given an error message describing the problem.  Did you read that message?  Did you understand it?

Comment: Question is what is a common functionality? What is the reason of keeping different object types in single container? This will clarify best possible solution.

Comment: A simple solution would be to have a vector of pointers to an interface where you can store pointers to implementations (I did that for handling messages), but the question is if it can also be done with templates. Interesting.

Comment: What C++ standard you can use? What is the set of `T` types?

Comment: Go look up virtual functions in your favourite text book.

Comment: @MarekR I am using c++ 17. I am keeping different object types in single container becoz I I want to have arbitrary number of objects and they all do the same thing/interface(update). Since update() takes a type, I can't assign it as a virtual function in base class. So I am stuck now.

Comment: @user3443615 you're right about the different argument types, but that is going to a bitch anyway because you have to know what type is needed which is difficult with a heterogeneous container. There is `std::any`, but that just moves the problem. If, as in your example, the number and order of types is fixed, then `std::tuple` can be used.

Comment: You need explain what kind of functionality you want to achieve so we could help you. You are keeping explaining your solution of a problem which apparently do not work and this will not help us to provide alternative better solution. If `update` should accept different type, then there is no common functionality. Looks like you should have multiple vectors for each type.

Comment: Did you check `std::variant`?